# AS86 Set Origin Address (x86 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, as86

Does anyone know how to set an origin address using AS86 syntax?

With NASM, you would put, for example (in a BIOS bootloader): ORG 0x7c00.

Does anyone know what the AS86 equivalent is? Or what the functional equivalent would be?

I'm using AS86 because I'm compiling programs with the 16-bit assembly output from BCC (Bruce's C Compiler). If anyone knows of a true 16-bit C compiler that will produce NASM-compatible assembly, that would also essentially solve my problem (since, unlike with AS86, I have had no issue with getting NASM's raw binaries to work using particular memory address offsets).

2/1 Edit with example AS86 code:

```
ORG 0x7c00

USE16

mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x61
xor bx, bx
int 0x10

ORG 0x7DFE
.word 0xAA55
```

Generated symbol file (seems correct):

```
+ 00007C00 ----- $start
+ 00007E00 ----- $end
```

And the generated binary is 512 bytes, meaning (I think) that the ORG directive at the end is padding out the rest of the file in the same way as would happen with NASM using the "times" directive.

Thanks!

Final edit: So this was solved. From the help I received, the solution to the origin address issue was to put the origin address at the beginning using the ORG directive and then to also use the ORG directive at the end to specify the memory address at which the program should be located at that particular point in the file. Then, the assembly language file has to be compiled in as86 using the -s option to generate a symbol file.

Then, the reason this code wasn't working even though the memory address issue was solved was because I hadn't read the man pages very carefully and was effectively loading (into the registers) the contents of the memory locations specified in the operands I was using, rather than their immediate values.

So, after fixing that issue as well, the test code runs on boot and prints the 'a' character as expected.

Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: According to the manual page `org` should work, and it does for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: In AS86, I was using the org directive to pad with '0' bytes (to make nice 512 byte binaries that I could write to the sectors of a virtual floppy image that virtualbox will accept). So to me, AS86's "org" directive was equivalent to NASM's "times" directive. When I tried to use the "org" directive in the same way that I would use it in NASM (e.g., ORG 0x7e00), AS86 generated a ~2kilobyte binary file (instead of the intended 512 byte file). Do you have an example of how you used "org" with AS86 to specify an origin address and not to act as a byte padder? Thanks

Comment: You likely missed the `-s` command line option in the manual: _"if there's no -s option the file starts at location 0"_.

Comment: @Jester do you know how in particular you would use the -s flag? On the command line, I used "as86 -0 boot.asm -s boot.sym -b boot.bin". I'll post my current example AS86 bootloader code in the main post above with an edit. In short, the generated symbol file is showing the correct start and end addresses. And the generated binary file is 512 bytes (meaning that the padding is also working). But the binary doesn't work when I load it up on virtualbox. The NASM-generated binary with that particular bios interrupt code in the middle works fine, by contrast. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: So clearly there's some different in the binary you created.  It's only 512 bytes so you could basically diff the binaries. You could use the Unix command `cmp -l as86.bin nasm.bin` to see if they're different, and if so where.  Or disassemble them both with `ndisasm` and diff the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue was needing to use `-s`, as pointed out by Jester's comment.

As you noted, the code then seemed to be laid out correctly but still didn't work.  So I assembled your code and disassembled the output, and the issue became clear.

`as86` uses different syntax than `nasm` and other traditional Intel-style assemblers.  In particular, an instruction like `mov ah, 0x0e` is parsed as what you might understand as `mov ah, [0x0e]`; it's a move of one byte from memory address `0x0e`.  Obviously, you meant to load the immediate value `0x0e` so you have to write `mov ah, #0x0e`.

It seems like it would be a good idea to read carefully through [the `as86` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bin86/as86.1.en.html) before proceeding any further.